# Youtube iPhone URL shemes

Tags: objective-c, ios, url, youtube, mobile-safari

How can I launsh my app when there is a YouTube URL opened in Safari?
I searched on the Internet very long, but I didn't see a possibility to do this, because it is an http:// link. But the Google YouTube app does this, can anybody tell me how this works?

Thanks

Comment: Refer [iPhoneURLScheme_YouTubeLinks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/YouTubeLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007895-SW1) link and get helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this, is to create your own URL Scheme, as denoted here - [Implementing URL Schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50)

You can then detect to modify any YouTube URLs so they fit in with your app's URL Scheme with JavaScript `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:yourJavaScript]`

Here's the kicker. You can only modify pages from within your own web-browsing instance - i.e. creating a UIWebView inside your app, but then, your already in your app, which will render this entire exercise pointless.

You can however, use this method to communicate from within a suite of apps that you've built, so you could maintain your URL scheme across a web-browsing one, which will launch apps in your video playing one.

You can't do this with Mobile Safari though.

Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: So there is no way to look up this YouTube URLSheme? they are defenetly using one!

Comment: YouTube is mentioned in the Apple Developer docs, this suggests that Apple have personally added this URL scheme in. In iOS6, this URL scheme, almost certainly links to their proprietary Video app, as opposed to YouTube (I would assume). Prior to iOS6 YouTube was automatically included with iPad/iPhone and was the dedicated app for Video viewing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can launch your own app with YouTube link in Safari. Unlike Android Intents, iOS has only one way to launch other apps - url schemes. So when you're trying to open YouTube link in Safari it just calls

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: @"some url scheme"]
```

Where "some url scheme" is used internally (it is unknown) and only YouTube app can handle it.

Comment: for everybody else having this problem: it is youtube://videoIDhere(for example "ynBpKpjq5Oo" for "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynBpKpjq5Oo"). I just tried this and happily it works.

Comment: you mean that your app opens using scheme youtube:// ?